# Fancy Handwritten Post it document

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, boxes

Recently I was asked by a professor to gather comments from all my class mates, anonimusly, regading his way of teaching in order to improve or keep some aspects. I thought to write each comment in a post it like box, which will be rotated, in handwritten fonts.

This means that every post-it box will have different orientation and different handwritten font type. I have found some really good looking handwritten font styles [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html).  So far I could only use `mdframed` but the result is not as fancy as I thought it will be.

My code is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    calc,%
    fadings,%
    shadings%
}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,snakes,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\newcommand{\Cloud}[2][180]% [angle], content
{   \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \node[align=center, draw, shading=ball, text=white, cloud callout, cloud puffs=17, cloud puff arc=140, callout pointer segments=3, anchor=pointer, callout relative pointer={(#1:2 cm )}, aspect=4,scale=0.5] at (-3ex,0.5ex) {#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrameBlue}{%
    linecolor=red,
    outerlinewidth=0.5pt,
    roundcorner=5pt,
    innertopmargin=\baselineskip,
    innerbottommargin=\baselineskip,
    innerrightmargin=20pt,
    innerleftmargin=20pt,
    backgroundcolor=blue!20!white}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrameBlue]
        What a great lesson with a lot of fun features!!!
        \end{mdframed}
            \Cloud[30]{Have a great Summer}
    \end{document}
```

My output looks like that(it's in Greek Sorry!)

[image]

Any idea on how to do it post-it like with handwritten fonts in greek?

Comment: @HarishKumar: You are absolutely right. I've edited my question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 5):

With regards to fonts:

- [Xiomara](http://www.fontspace.com/nymphont/xiomara) covers Latin, Greek and Cyrillic and is free for personal use.
- If you're running Windows Vista or later, Segoe Script covers Greek.
- [Pecita](http://pecita.eu/police-en.php) covers many, many languages, and is released under the Open Font Licence.
- [VAG-Handwritten](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/VAG-HandWritten) covers Latin and Greek and is released under the GPL.

To use these fonts in your document, you'll have to compile with XeTeX or LuaTeX. Install the font in your operating system as you would to use it with any other program, then load it with the `fontspec` package, with

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\vaghandwritten{VAG-Handwritten}
```

This defines the command `\vaghandwritten`, which you can use to switch to the font for the rest of the current group. You can look at the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) documentation for more options.

An example document, using `\marginpar` to typeset the notes, might look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\vaghandwritten{VAG-Handwritten}

\begin{document}
This is some document text.\marginpar{\vaghandwritten This is a note, typeset in the handwritten font.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I believe that `VAG-Handwritten` suits me best. How to use them in my `LaTeX` document?

Comment: Can you include a full document to help others with varying degree of TeX knowledge who happen to find this question?